# Filtering on Scala Option[Set]

Tags: scala, filtering, scala-option

I have a Scala value of type `Option[Set[String]]` that I am trying to use in a collection `filter` method:

```
val opt: Option[Set[String]] = ...

collection.filter {
  value =>
  opt match {
    case Some(set) => set.contains(value)
    case None => true
  }
}
```

If the `opt` value is `Some(...)` I want to use the enclosed `Set` to filter the collection, otherwise I want to include all items in the collection.

Is there a better (more idiomatic) way to use the `Option` (`map`, `filter`, `getOrElse`, etc.)?

The `opt` comes from an optional command line argument containing a list of terms to include. If the command line argument is missing, then include all terms.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd use the fact that `Set[A]` extends `A => Boolean` and pass the constant function returning `true` to `getOrElse`:

```
val p: String => Boolean = opt.getOrElse(_ => true)
```

Or:

```
val p = opt.getOrElse(Function.const(true) _)
```

Now you can just write `collection.filter(p)`. If you want a one-liner, either of the following will work as well:

```
collection filter opt.getOrElse(_ => true)
collection filter opt.getOrElse(Function.const(true) _)
```

Comment: What is a purpose of Function.const(...) BTW?

Comment: @om-nom-nom http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5924875/whats-the-purpose-of-function-const

Comment: If the collection contains a custom class instead of `String`, is there any way to check one of the instance fields (for example `name`) using your method? If a do a `map` on the collection to convert it to `String`, I lose the class contents, which I need later in the method chain. BTW, your method has worked very nicely for my String collections. Thanks.

Comment: @Ralph: If you've defined `p` as above you can just use `collection.filter(x => p(x.name))`.

Answer (score 6):

It seems a bit wasteful to filter on `_ => true` so I would prefer

```
opt match {
  case Some(s) => collection filter s
  case None    => collection
}
```

I guess this equates to:

```
opt map (collection filter) getOrElse collection
```

Comment: I agree that your solution is cleaner than the original version, and might be preferable for large collections, inside loops, etc., but in this case it feel like premature optimization—this is an operation that presumably only happens once, and on a very small collection (command line arguments), so I'd pick the more expressive version.